# jquery content dynamically

Tags: jquery, css

Basically I've attempted to code jquery to switch object's(div,class) inside one enclosing div and replace it accordingly in three different ways depending on the nav button that's clicked, with the default being a landing page/animation.

I'd like to replace the landing page's content to change dynamically so I will not write three separate pages of code, just change elements inside one div when visitors click on two separate buttons. The only problem I'm having is probably my syntax...I get the code working to hide the element...which is as typed below,
as I attempt to removeClass/addClass or toggleClass I fight with it for hours to no avail.

This is my current version---another thing that I question currently is why the .hide(this); on my second function fades the content out while .hide() alone does not fade, I like the effect of fading but I'm sure I can figure the proper way to do it because it may be a quirk??Not sure

```
**$(document).ready(function() {
$("**#oneway**").click(function() {
$("**.lee**:first").hide();
});
$("**#secondway**").click(function() {
$("**.lee**:first").hide(this);
});**
```

I'll write the corresponding HTML and CSS
and thank you for your time for reading

HTML

```
<div class="**enlosing**">

<nav>
<ul class="Nav">

<li id="stuff"><a href="blah.html" target="_self" >STUFF</a></li>
<li id="quality"><a href="**#oneway**" target="_self">QUALITY</a></li>
<li id="stuff2"><a href="blahblah.html" target="_self">STUFFALSO</a></li>
<li id="contact"><a href="**#secondway**" target="_self">CONTACT</a></li>


</ul>
</nav>

</div>


<div class="**lee**">

<div class="**ex**">    
<div class="place">
<a class="gotoplace" href="http://www.link.com" target="_self"></a>
</div>
</div>
<div/>
```

CSS

```
.ex{


display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0;
background-image: url(../img/seal.png);
background-position: left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
margin-left:center;
height:100%;
width:100%;

}
```

I've been attempting to get .ex to change dynamically in multiple ways while keeping the rest of the page the same.

As this question has been asked various ways on this site I have gone through many but can't distinguish my problem as of now. If there is an answer or question that specifically pertains to my code excuse my negligence.

Comment: Why are there `*`'s in your attributes?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `href` value of your links as a jQuery selector, which you can't do. At least not directly.

Two options, either use their id's or use the `href` correctly as an attribute.

1)

```
$('#stuff2 a').click(...)
```

2)

```
$('a[href="**#secondway**"]').click(...)
```